# Constraint to select certain items in MiniZinc

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I am trying to create a model to work with a problem derived from the **Set Packing problem.**

In this case, I have a parameter called **nRecipes** that represents the number of recipes and another called **nIngred** that represents the number of ingredients. Each recipe has a specific nutritional value that is represented by the **value** parameter.

I want to choose a menu with at most **numDishes** recipes, so that the nutritional value of the menu is maximized. Another restriction is that each chosen dish does not contain any ingredients in the other chosen dishes.

I have tried the following:

```
int: nRecipes;                                  
set of int: RECIPES = 1..nRecipes;              

array[RECIPES] of int: value;                   

int: nIngred;                             
set of int: INGREDIENTS = 1..nIngred;    
int: numDishes;                                 
  
array[INGREDIENTS] of set of RECIPES: group;

var set of RECIPES: menu; 


array[1..numDishes] of var RECIPES: selected_menu;

constraint menu <= selected_menu; % Error
constraint alldifferent(selected_menu);

solve maximize value;
```

Test example:

```
nRecipes = 10;
value = [10,8,4,2,6,9,5,3,8,10];
group = [{1,4,6},{1,2,6,7},{1,3,6,8}, 
        {1,2,3},{2,9,10},{5,6,8,10},
        {7,8,10},{1,3,5}];
numDishes = 3;
nIngred = 8;
```

Expected Output:

```
Value:20
Recipe:{1,10}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, where the `group` variable has been flipped around to hold the ingredients per recipe (also renamed it `ingredients`). Now you can use `all_disjoint` to formulate the constraint that the selected dishes may not use the same ingredients.

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: nRecipes;                                  
set of int: RECIPES = 1..nRecipes;              

array[RECIPES] of int: value;                   

int: nIngred;                             
set of int: INGREDIENTS = 1..nIngred;    
int: numDishes;                                 
    
array[RECIPES] of set of INGREDIENTS: ingredients;

array[1..numDishes] of var RECIPES: selected_menu;

constraint all_disjoint([ingredients[selected_menu[i]] | i in 1..numDishes]);

var int: obj = sum([value[selected_menu[i]] | i in 1..numDishes]);
solve maximize obj;

output ["total value=\(obj)\n"] ++ 
["selected_menu=\(selected_menu)\n"] ++
["ingredients=\([ingredients[selected_menu[i]] | i in 1..numDishes])\n"];
```

running with the data:

```
numDishes = 2;
nIngred = 8;
nRecipes = 10;
value = [10,8,4,2,6,9,5,3,8,10];

ingredients = [{1,2,3,4},{2,4,5},{3,4,8}, 
        {1},{6,8},{1,2,3,6},
        {2,7},{3,6,7},{5},{5,6,7}];
```

gives:

```
total value=20
selected_menu=[10, 1]
ingredients=[5..7, 1..4]
```

**Edit:** A new version that allows choosing less dishes than `num_dishes` dishes if that gives a better objective value. This is done through the variable `dishes` that represents the number of actually chosen dishes. Non-used menus will have a value of `0`.

```
int: nRecipes;                                  
set of int: RECIPES = 1..nRecipes;              
set of int: RECIPES0 = 0..nRecipes;

array[RECIPES] of int: value;                   

int: nIngred;                             
set of int: INGREDIENTS = 1..nIngred;    
int: numDishes;                                 
    
var 1..numDishes: maxDishes;
    
array[INGREDIENTS] of set of RECIPES: group;

array[1..numDishes] of var RECIPES0: selected_menu;

constraint forall(i in INGREDIENTS)
    (sum(m in selected_menu)(m in group[i]) <= 1);

var int: obj = sum([value[selected_menu[i]] | i in 1..maxDishes]);
solve maximize obj;

output["Value: ", show(obj), "\nRecipe: ", show([selected_menu[d] | d in 1..maxDishes])];
```

**Edit:** Another version using a set to represent `selected_menu`.

```
int: nRecipes;                                  
set of int: RECIPES = 1..nRecipes;              

array[RECIPES] of int: value;                   

int: nIngred;                             
set of int: INGREDIENTS = 1..nIngred;    
int: numDishes;
                            
array[INGREDIENTS] of set of RECIPES: group;

var 1..numDishes: dishes;
var set of RECIPES: selected_menu;

% each ingredients may appear in at most one recipe
constraint forall(i in INGREDIENTS)
    (card(selected_menu intersect group[i]) <= 1);
    
constraint card(selected_menu) <= dishes;    

var int: obj = sum([value[m] | m in selected_menu]);
solve maximize obj;

output["Value: ", show(obj), "\nRecipe: ", show(selected_menu)];
```

Comment: Added a version using the original parameters.

Comment: The `card()` function gives the cardinality of a set. The `array2set()` function converts the array `selected_menu` to a set (so that we can use `intersect`).

Comment: You can use `sort(selected_menu)` in the output statement or add a symmetry breaking constraint like `constraint increasing(selected_menu);`

Comment: If you convert to set (`array2set()`) you will get the desired output.

Comment: `output["Recipe: ", show(array2set(selected_menu))];` would give the desired output.

Comment: I edited the question because the model is inconsistent for some examples. I attach one of them.

Comment: I added a modified model handling the case where it is better to select less than the maximum number of allowed menus.

Comment: I edited the answer to not use global constraints. Why do you need `var set of RECIPES: menu;`?

Comment: Added another model where a set is used to represent `selected_menu`